# Separation in logistic regression in a complex survey?

Tags: regression, logistic, survey, separation

Firth's penalized maximum likelihood estimates, exact logistic regression and Bayesian logistic regression (e.g. bayesglm) can account for separation in logistic regression. But how to account for probability weights and complex survey designs in these methods (e.g. in R or Stata)?

Comment: for R look at  http://r-survey.r-forge.r-project.org/survey/survey-wss.pdf and  https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Complex+Surveys%3A+A+Guide+to+Analysis+Using+R-p-9781118210932